# Import non-ES6 module into webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am a little lost when trying to integrate a javascript library which is not an ES6 module.

I am trying to import 'jointjs' into my webpack project.

How can I import the function joint?

I can do this:

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
window.joint = require('jointjs');
```

And then directly in the view, I can use a script tag to put my javascript. But if I try to import the joint function like this:

```
import 'joint' from 'jointjs';
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
//...
```

It raises an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dia' of undefined

How can I make it work?

I have the feeling that I have to use ProvidePlugins, Exports-Loader or something like that... But it is not clear at all for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import like this for non es6 code

```
const joint = require('jointjs');
```

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do not add quotes to the import

```
import * as joint from 'jointjs';
```

If it doesn't work, you can probably try using require as

```
const joint = require('jointjs');
```

Comment: I would recommend import * that not good approach since it can import whole library into your app